# Calculting time of filling a tank with inflow and leakage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A tap takes $36$ hours extra to fill a tank due to a leakage equivalent
>   to half of its inflow. The inflow can fill in how many hours?

The purpose of asking this question is to understand the right answer because my book and one website are giving totally different answers.

**Source 1:** Answer available in [My book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vi8rDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA490&lpg=PA490&dq=A%20tap%20takes%2036%20hours%20extra%20to%20fill%20a%20tank%20due%20to%20a%20leakage%20equivalent%20to%20half%20of%20its%20inflow.&source=bl&ots=rYHa8kWOqC&sig=g7jvlapfBKd-pWkLz-Daj8NHyFo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR0vi2nNjOAhVDLY8KHZTtBbIQ6AEIQjAH#v=onepage&q=A%20tap%20takes%2036%20hours%20extra%20to%20fill%20a%20tank%20due%20to%20a%20leakage%20equivalent%20to%20half%20of%20its%20inflow.&f=false)   *(Question 124 in page 490)* is $18$ with the following explanation.

> [image]

**source 2:** Answer available in [careerbless](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=3319#) is $36$ with [this explanation](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=3319#)

**Source 3** Answer available in [staging.parikshawale.com](https://staging.parikshawale.com/questions/tap-takes-36-hours-extra-fill-tank-due-leakage-equivalent-half-its-inflow-inflow-can-fill-tank) is $18$ with [this explanation](https://staging.parikshawale.com/questions/tap-takes-36-hours-extra-fill-tank-due-leakage-equivalent-half-its-inflow-inflow-can-fill-tank)

Please help me to figure our the right solution.

Comment: I think the question (the one from the book, not yours) is poorly worded.  The question should be phrased: If there is no leakage, how long will it take for the inflow to fill the tank?

Comment: @Aweygan, agreed. but all sources I mentioned calculate "how long will it take for the inflow to fill the tank?" only and still different answers

Comment: Ahh, I did not check those links.  I'll post my thoughts as an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T$ be the time it takes to fill the tank when there is both inflow and leakage. Let $t$ be the time is takes to fill the tank when there is only inflow.

Let $f$ be the rate of inflow of the water, measured in units of tanks per time. Then we have $$\frac{1}{f}=t \quad \wedge \quad \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}f}=T$$

But we also have $T=t+36$. Can you take it from here?

---

Answer:

> From the first two equations, we get $T=2t$, which makes sense; it takes twice the amount of time to fill the tank, since we have halved the effective inflow. We then insert this into the third equation, which gives $$2t=t+36 \Rightarrow t=36.$$

Comment: Again there is conflict, your answer appears right to me and is as per the answer in careerbless. But, @Aweygan's answer is 18
. looking both in deep